What is the physical intuition behind ΔH and ΔU being different for reversible adiabatic cooling of an ideal gas?
This week's homework for my thermodynamics class included the following problem:

One mole of an ideal monoatomic gas (for which $\bar{C_v} = \frac{3}{2}R)$ is cooled reversibly and adiabatically from $T_1$ to $T_2$, where $T_1 >T_2$. Calculate $\Delta U$, $\Delta H$, $q$, and $w$.

My solution is as follows:
Because the process is adiabatic, $q=0$ and thus by the 1st law of thermodynamics $$\Delta U = q + w = 0+w = w$$
For ideal gases, $U$ is a state function of $n$ and $T$: $$U(n, T) = n\bar{C_V}T$$
Consequently, $$ \Delta U = \Delta \left(n\bar{C_V}T \right) = n\bar{C_V} \Delta T$$
By definition of enthalpy ($H = U + pV$) and the ideal gas law ($pV=nRT$), $$\Delta H = \Delta U + \Delta \left( pV \right) = \Delta U + \Delta(nRT) = \Delta U + nR \Delta T$$
Plugging in $\Delta U$, we get that $$\Delta H = n\bar{C_V} \Delta T + nR \Delta T = n \left(\bar{C_V} + R \right) \Delta T$$
Given that $\bar{C_P} = \bar{C_V} + R$ for ideal gases, this seems to suggest that $$\Delta H = n \bar{C_P} \Delta T$$
In this case, $\Delta T < 0$ and thus $\Delta H < \Delta U$. This leaves me with a few questions:

When does the relation $\Delta H = n \bar{C_P} \Delta T$ hold? Is it only for adiabatic expansion/compression of monoatomic ideal gases, or is it more generally applicable?
Is there a more direct way to come to this solution?
Why don't $\Delta U$, $\Delta H$, and $w$ match up here? I understand that they are different state functions, but I'm just confused as to where the energy $\Delta H - w$ is "going"... Is it simply that the cooling is causing the gas to take up less space on top of the work $w$ it is doing on its surroundings as it cools?


Please let me know if I made any mistakes in notation here. I'm still getting a grasp on it and am getting confused by how variable the notation can be between sources.

$w$ is not a state function, although $\Delta(p V)$ is. Your intuition seems right. Compare to the isothermal case for which $\Delta U =\Delta H =0$.

Your equation for $\Delta H$ is valid for all changes of an ideal gas, as for ideal gases $H$ is a state function solely dependent on temperature.
Your method is pretty direct.
$\Delta U$ and $\Delta H$ don’t have to match up in this problem, as for ideal gases
$$
\begin{align}
\Delta H &= \Delta U + \Delta(pV) \\
&= \Delta U + \Delta(nRT) \\
&= \Delta U + nR \Delta T
\end{align}
$$
which means that $\Delta H = \Delta U$ if and only if $\Delta T = 0$. In this case, $\Delta T \neq 0$ and thus $\Delta H \neq \Delta U$.
By the way, your analysis so far does not require reversiblity.

There are some situations in which $\Delta H$ and $\Delta U$ do seem to match up (e.g. the isothermal case @Buck Thorn mentioned) and I haven't yet built an intuition as to when this is the case. Upon reflection, it seems like $\Delta U = \Delta H \iff \Delta T = 0$ for ideal gases. I guess I was just confusing adiabatic with isothermal.
